# using Join with entity framework object query. Navigation property still shows all the entities of the joined entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, navigation-properties

My EF object query is:

```
from customer in MCDBContext.Customers
join customerCase in MCDBContext.CustomerCases on customer.CustomerID equals customerCase.CustomerID
join customerCasePhone in MCDBContext.CustomerCasePhones on customerCase.CustomerCaseID equals customerCasePhone.CustomerCaseID
**join customerCaseAddress in MCDBContext.CustomerCaseAddresses on customerCase.CustomerCaseID equals customerCaseAddress.CustomerCaseID**

where customer.CustomerPIN.Equals(pin, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
        customerCasePhone.PhoneNumber.Equals(phoneNumber, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
        **customerCaseAddress.AddressTypeID == 6** &&
        customerCase.IsActive == true && customerCasePhone.IsActive == true && customerCaseAddress.Active == true && customer.IsActive == true
select customer;
```

In the code:

```
var customers = getmethod() //calls the above object query method.
```

now when I do `customers.First().CustomerAddresses();` //Returns all the customer addresses, though I filtered it to do only of TypeID = 6 in my object query. Why so? I don't want to write the filter condition again. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does not return *all* addresses per customer. It doesn't return any address at all. The addresses get loaded afterwards due to lazy loading when you access the navigation properties. That's a second query and lazy loading always returns *all* addresses.

If you want to get the desired result in a single database query you need a projection to load customer AND addresses in the `select` operation.

Leveraging your navigation properties (I guess, you have some, because of the tag under your question), it would look like this:

```
var result = MCDBContext.Customers
    .Where(customer => customer.IsActive && customer.CustomerPIN.Equals(
           pin, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        && customer.CustomerCases.Any(ccase =>
               ccase.IsActive
            && ccase.CustomerCasePhones.Any(phone => 
                   phone.IsActive
                && phone.PhoneNumber.Equals(
                   phoneNumber, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            && ccase.CustomerCaseAddresses.Any(address =>
                   address.IsActive
                && address.AddressTypeID == 6)))
    .Select(customer => new
    {
        Customer = customer,
        // you can also fetch here cases and phones, if you need them
        Addresses = customer.CustomerCases.Where(ccase => ccase.IsActive)
            .Select(ccase => ccase.CustomerCaseAddresses
               .Where(address => address.IsActive && address.AddressTypeID == 6))
    })
    .ToList();
```

This does not populate the addresses collection in the object tree of customer but only returns a list of anonymous objects: Each entry has the customer and the filtered addresses of this customer.

Comment: Cool, thanks! That made things very clear. I'd go with lazy loading and do my filtering there rather than deal with the anonymous collection objects.